# Conditional Probability for Network Science

Tags: conditional-probability, graph-theory

My network has 100 nodes and 196 edges. Each node has an attribute of "smoker" or "non-smoker". There are 5 smokers and 95 non-smokers.

I want to know the probability of being a smoker given that you are connected to a smoker.

16 nodes in the network are connected to a smoker.

2 nodes are connected to a smoker AND are a smoker themselves.

I want to set up a conditional probability P(A|B) where:

A = node is a smoker

B = node has a neighbor who is a smoker

P(A) = 5/100

P(B) = 16/100

P(A∧B) = 2/100

So P(A|B) = .02/.16 = .125

Is this the right way to do this?
I'm a little uncertain about using the number of nodes as the denominator for my probabilities. Might edges make sense too? Particularly for P(B)--the sum of degrees of smoker nodes divided by total edges. In this case 18/196.

Also, if I loop through the network and look at all neighbors, there are 392 (196*2). My graph is not directed, but might this number be relevant too. Thinking of each neighbor-neighbor relationship as a ball in a bowl. In the context of probability, is source->target identical to target->source if the graph is not directed? Or should I be considering each neighbor for each node's perspective?

Visualization below: Blue nodes are smokers

[image]

Comment: If you want to increase the likelihood of someone answering your question, please include pictures.

Comment: @mhdadk okay I added a visualization of the graph. I'm not sure if I have any pictures that help articulate the question though

Comment: While the plot of the graph is refreshing to see on stat.SE, you could probably just summarize the required information for this problem in a contingency table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find the people who are connected to smokers.

Of those people, how many are smokers?

Done.

The fact that there is a graph could lead one to believe that fancy graph analysis is necessary, and you could do something with how many connections one has to smokers or second-degree connections (connected to no smokers, but connected to a non-smoker who has a smoker connection), but I do believe it is this simple to solve the stated problem.

Comment: (+1) *The fact that there is a graph could lead one to believe that fancy graph analysis is necessary*. It can be tempting to use sophisticated representations such as graphs, hypergraphs, and simplicial complexes, but sometimes you just need a probability measure on sets.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and comment. I think that I'm guilty of this. The graph I'm actually working on is more complicated than this but it's helpful to think of the nodes as belonging to a set. I can even be explicit about it and add a yes/no 'connected_to_smoker' attribute, group like nodes together as sets and then find the intersection of the 'smoker' set and the 'is_connected_to_smoker' set. Thanks again.